# HTML. При нажатии на кнопку всплывает форма

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Ребят, очень нужно. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку всплывала форма с с полями, куда пользователь мог бы внести данные и тем самым зарегистрироваться.

```js
document.getElementById('blablabla').style.display = 'none';

function blablabla() {
  document.getElementById('blablabla').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<button onclick='blablabla()'>Показать форму</button>
<div id='blablabla'>
  <form role="form" action="/requestFine" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
    <label>Ім'я:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nameReq">
    <label>Прізвище:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastNameReq">
    <label>Телефон:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telReq">
    <label>Опис:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textReq">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: А информацию о пользователях где будете хранить?

Comment: @РустамГимранов база данных

Comment: Просто из вопроса не понятно, что уже сделано, что делаете, где не получается.

Comment: Где ваши попытки решить задачу?

Comment: @РустамГимранов У меныя лишь форма с отправкйо данных в базу (инпути и батон)

Comment: @РустамГимранов Добавил в вопрос код с формой

Comment: У вас есть форма, при нажатии на кнопку `Отправить`, будет отпавляться данные формы на `/requestFine`. В чем вопрос?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вопрос в том, как сделать всплывашку, а не сабмитить форму

Comment: Я видоизменил Ваш код, чтобы он мог выполняться в песочнице Stack Overflow. Он вполне себе работает. Что Вас не устраивает в том, как он работает сейчас?

Answer (score 2):

Через `display: none/block`, если нужно.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const form = document.querySelector('#blablabla');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.add('open');
});
```

```css
#blablabla {
  display: none;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

#blablabla.open {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Показать форму</button>
<div id="blablabla">
  <form role="form" action="/requestFine" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
    <label>Ім'я:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nameReq">
    <label>Прізвище:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastNameReq">
    <label>Телефон:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telReq">
    <label>Опис:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textReq">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**UPD. С Popup окном. (Может пригодится)**

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const form = document.querySelector('#blablabla');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.add('open');
  popup.classList.add('popup_open');
});
```

```css
#blablabla {
  display: none;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

#blablabla.open {
  display: block;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  display: none;
}

.popup_open {
  display: block;
}

.popup__container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 588px;
  width: 100%;
}

.popup__wrapper {
  padding: 40px;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Показать форму</button>

<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__container">
    <div class="popup__wrapper">
      <div id="blablabla">
        <form role="form" action="/requestFine" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
          <label>Ім'я:</label>
          <input type="text" name="nameReq">
          <label>Прізвище:</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastNameReq">
          <label>Телефон:</label>
          <input type="text" name="telReq">
          <label>Опис:</label>
          <input type="text" name="textReq">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы форма всплывала, можно реализовать это по разному.

Лично я думаю, что автор говоря ***`всплывала`***, имеет ввиду плавность. Конечно, можно добиться плавности и с помощью `js`, но лучше `css`.

И еще один важный момент: свойство `display:none; && display:block;` Трансформации не поддаются. Так что если нужна плавность без `opacity` не обойтись.

```js
const formWrap = document.getElementById('form-wrap');

function openForm() {
    formWrap.classList.add('open');
}
```

```css
#form-wrap {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

#form-wrap.open {
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='openForm()'>Показать форму</button>
<div id='form-wrap'>
  <form role="form" action="/requestFine" autocomplete="off" method="POST">
    <label>Ім'я:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nameReq">
    <label>Прізвище:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastNameReq">
    <label>Телефон:</label>
    <input type="text" name="telReq">
    <label>Опис:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textReq">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

> P.S. А если  все же `display:none; && display:block;` обязательны, то
>   реализовать по другому....